# WebGL in wxWebView

Tags: webgl, wxwidgets

I have a simple WebGL file which renders fine in both Chrome and IE11.

However, [wxWebView](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html) just shows a blank.  Should it be able to show the WebGL?  The wxWebView shows javascript just fine.

I have tried setting the registry value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION*executable* to 11001 as suggested [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) but there is no effect.

Here is a further simplified script.  In a real browser it shows "gl OK3" but in wxWebView it just shows "canvas OK2";

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

   WebGL test

<p id="message"></p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="300"></canvas>

<script src="webgl-utils.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = myFunction;

function myFunction() {

    var message = document.getElementById("message");
    message.innerHTML = "message OK1";


    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    message.innerHTML = " canvas OK2";

    var gl = getWebGLContext(canvas);
    message.innerHTML = "gl OK3";

}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it.

Adding the following to the html ensures the latest version of the renderer is used

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```